# Checking whether an int is palindrome or not without converting into a string?

Tags: java, string, int, palindrome

```
public class Palindrome {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int x = 121;
        int res = 0;
        while (x > 0) {
            res = res * 10 + (x % 10);
            x /= 10;
        }
        if (x - res == 0) {
            System.out.println("True" + res);
        } else
            System.out.println("False" + res);
    }
}
```

Hello! This code is to check if an integer is a palindrome without converting the `int` to a `String`. For some reason, the computer thinks `res` is not same as `x` though both represent the number `121`. Appreciate your help and thanks in advance!

Comment: They aren't the same, you are doing x/=10 which changes x, and at the end x will become 0.

Comment: *the computer thinks res is not same as x* because they are not. x started as 121 and after the loop is 0.

Comment: `x - res == 0` is a fancy way of writing `x == res` :-)

Comment: This is just a rough code and I've rearranged each line multiple times to see of that's what causing the errro. I've been superstitious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were close. Here is a solution building on what you did:

```
static bool isPalindrome (int n1, int n2) {
    return getReverseInteger(n1) == n2;
}

static int getReverseInteger (int n) {
    int nReversed = 0;
    while (n > 0) {
      int digit = n % 10;
      nReversed = nReversed * 10 + digit;
      n = (n - digit) / 10;
    }
    return nReversed;
}
```

Comment: Would it work even if you just leave that as n=n/10 or am i missing somethung?

Comment: No, you need to subtract the value of n % 10. Example: 121/10 = 12.1, 12.1/10 = 1.21, 1.21/10 = 0.21 (i.e. never reaches 0).

Comment: (121 - 1)/10 = 12, (12 - 2)/10 = 1, (1-1/10) = 0

Comment: But since it is ```int```, it will only take 12.1 as a whole number which is just 12.Guess I'm not wrong

Comment: Yes, actually you are right. I was thinking of float division. But if x is an int, then you can just divide by 10 each time.